# Warning and get error in admin modification page OpenCart 2.1.0.2

Tags: php, opencart, fopen, opencart2.x, ocmod

When I hit the refresh button in the `admin > Extensions > Modifications` page the page crashes and produces a page of failure errors in OpenCart 2.1.0.2

Following error got. Please help me. how can i fixed this issue.

> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/onlybrands1/public_html/system/modification/system/engine/action.php)
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/onlybrands1/public_html/admin/controller/extension/modification.php
>   on line 408
>
> Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   /home/onlybrands1/public_html/admin/controller/extension/modification.php
>   on line 410
>
> Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource,  boolean given
>   in 
>   /home/onlybrands1/public_html/admin/controller/extension/modification.php
>   on line 412
>
> Warning: 
>   fopen(/home/onlybrands1/public_html/system/modification/system/engine/loader.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/onlybrands1/public_html/admin/controller/extension/modification.php
>   on line 408
>
> Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource,  boolean given
>   in 
>   /home/onlybrands1/public_html/admin/controller/extension/modification.php
>   on line 410
>
> Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>            boolean given in
>            /home/onlybrands1/public_html/admin/controller/extension/modification.php
>           on line 412
>
> Warning: 
>   fopen(/home/onlybrands1/public_html/system/modification/system/library/config.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
>   /home/onlybrands1/public_html/admin/controller/extension/modification.php
>   on line 408
>
> Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>        boolean given in
>        /home/onlybrands1/public_html/admin/controller/extension/modification.php
>        on line 410
>
> Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource,  boolean given
>   in 
>   /home/onlybrands1/public_html/admin/controller/extension/modification.php
>   on line 412
>
> Warning: 
>   fopen(/home/onlybrands1/public_html/system/modification/system/library/language.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
>   /home/onlybrands1/public_html/admin/controller/extension/modification.php
>   on line 408
>
> Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource,  boolean given
>   in 
>   /home/onlybrands1/public_html/admin/controller/extension/modification.phpon
>   line 410
>
> Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource,  boolean given
>   in 
>   /home/onlybrands1/public_html/admin/controller/extension/modification.php
>   on line 412
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already  sent by
>   (output started at  /home/onlybrands1/public_html/admin/index.php:80)
>   in  /home/onlybrands1/public_html/system/library/response.php on line
>   12

Comment: Did you install any new extension?

Comment: No, I have not install any extension.

Comment: You've just installed opencart, right? I mean you're using the latest version of opencart without any modifications.

Comment: Yes, I have fresh installation OpenCart 2.1.0.2 without modification.

Comment: its for version 2.3? No have Directory /modification on project, sometimes a file xml modification.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have realized. this issue happen with wrong path in `config.php` file. has been modification folder location change(inside **storage** folder) than older version in OpenCart 2.1.0.2 by OpenCart.

and, Some user install OpenCart with quick setup feature from Hosting provider services. So, there, The proper path is not set in the `config.php` file with Hosting quick install feature in OpenCart 2.1.x. Version.

Here, You will need to set properly path for `DIR_CACHE` `DIR_DOWNLOAD` `DIR_LOGS` `DIR_MODIFICATION` `DIR_UPLOAD` in config.php(front & admin both config.php) file.

**Wrong path for OpenCart 2.1.0.2.** (this following path is for 2.0.x version)

```
define('DIR_CACHE', 'YOURSITE/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', 'YOURSITE/system/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', 'YOURSITE/system/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', 'YOURSITE/system/modification/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', 'YOURSITE/system/upload/');
```

**Correct Path for OpenCart 2.1.0.2.** Here, You will need to add `/storage/` in following path. (front & admin both config.php file)

```
define('DIR_CACHE', 'YOURSITE/system/storage/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', 'YOURSITE/system/storage/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', 'YOURSITE/system/storage/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', 'YOURSITE/system/storage/modification/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', 'YOURSITE/system/storage/upload/');
```

Hope this will helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the permission of the ~/system/modification/ folder to writeable (777).

Reference Link: http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=144373

Comment: I have already try. but, still issue. also, one more confusion. modification folder is by default available in `system/storage/modification/`

Comment: Do you still have all the errors mentioned in the question?

Comment: Yes, I have make system, storage and modification folder  to writeable (777). though, all error is still.

Comment: I have found solution. It was issue worng path in config.php file. Thanks.

Comment: @HarnishDesign, which path did u change? could please explain it. do u also use godaddy hosting?

Comment: @Princesodhi please see our answer. Hope this will helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
I was facing the similar issues from Loopback IP address. But on the live site, warnings were suppressed, since storage directory was manually moved to **YOURSITE/system/storage** and incorrectly configured in **config.php** and I couldn't get the Front-End display since it was showing

> Go to admin, find Extensions >> Modifications and click 'Refresh'
>   button. To apply the changes characterized by the uploaded
>   modification file

In **OpenCart 3.0.2.x** version, there is a notification from admin side:

> It is very important that you move the storage directory outside of the
>   web directory (e.g. public_html, www or htdocs)

The above quote was not showing in order to rectify the root cause of the issue and after correcting the config.php. It began to show in the pop-up screen and finally noticed, this was the issue. Follow the below procedure to get rid:

Changing the following code from both the front-end & admin-end in **config.php** file

From

`define('DIR_STORAGE', 'YOURSITE/storage/');`

To

`define('DIR_STORAGE', 'YOURSITE/system/storage/');`

and modifying

`$ sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/YOURFOLDER/*`

solved the issue from both front-end as well as in back-end